# detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed. | Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

I'm following a course on user login and registration and I'm getting this error and I don't know how to fix it `detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed.`

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('users/login/', views.MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    
    path('users/register/', views.registerUser, name='register'),

    path('users/profile/', views.getUserProfile, name="users-profile"),
    path('users/', views.getUsers, name="users"),
]
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def registerUser(request):
    data = request.data
    user = User.objects.create(
        first_name = data['name'],
        username = data['email'],
        email = data['email'],
        password = make_password(data['password'])
    )

    serializer = UserSerializerWithToken(user, many=False)

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    _id = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    isAdmin = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', '_id', 'username', 'email', "name", "isAdmin"]

    def get__id(self, obj):
        return obj.id

    def get_isAdmin(self, obj):
        return obj.is_staff
    
    def get_name(self, obj):
        name = obj.first_name
        if name == '':
            name = obj.email

        return name


class UserSerializerWithToken(UserSerializer):
    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', '_id', 'username', 'email', "name", "isAdmin", 'token']

    def get_token(self, obj):
        token = RefreshToken.for_user(obj)
        return str(token.access_token)
```

I'm not sure if this is the problem but I saw someone who said that since in views.py I have the view as `@api_view(['POST'])` I cant call it in urls.py the way I usually would. I would test that but I dont know of anyother way to do that

Comment: As your api is set to accept only post method **@api_view(['POST'])**, so can't simply hit the URL into browsers.

Comment: Try to run the API in postman using the POST method

Answer (score 0):

As your api is set to accept only the POST method, you can't simply hit the URL into the browser.  **api_view(['POST'])**

Try to run the API in postman using the POST method

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view

or add this

```
@api_view(['POST', 'GET'])
def registerUser(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return Response({'message': 'In get'})
    data = request.data
    user = User.objects.create(
        first_name = data['name'],
        username = data['email'],
        email = data['email'],
        password = make_password(data['password'])
    )

    serializer = UserSerializerWithToken(user, many=False)

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, your register API should be `POST`, not `GET`.

If you call your register API with GET method, the above error occurs.

You can simply test it with `curl` command (assuming runserver on port 8000).

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8000/users/register/
```

this  will  caouse "Method not allowed" error

```
curl -d '{"name":"value1", "email":"value2", "password": "value3"}' \
  -X POST http://localhost:8000/users/register/
```

this will work fine

Answer (score 0):

The default method is `GET` when we call through the browser. To test these endpoints by giving appropriate methods and data is to use rest API clients like

1. [POSTMAN](https://www.postman.com/)
2. [Thunder client if your using VS CODE](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rangav.vscode-thunder-client)
3. [`curl` way @fullswing answer, if you want minimal installation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75180009/5222075)

Answer (score 0):

In your api_view you are not using GET method that is the reason it is giving you error.
Kindly use GET method also and it should work. Check below for reference

```
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def registerUser(request):
     data = request.data
     user = User.objects.create(
     first_name = data['name'],
     username = data['email'],
     email = data['email'],
     password = make_password(data['password'])
 )
```